# MS SQL - should I use case is there other way?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help with SQL code.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
acIdent     acSubject        acCode
201.2.013   Jusel            F-203
201.2.013   Tehnomehanika    F-101 (1,5 mm)
```

I have an application that creates report, based on some filters.

This is what i want to achive:

When I choose acSubject 'Tehnomehanika', then return 'F-101 (1,5 mm)'
When I leave it blank it will be '', then return top 1 acCode - 'F-203'

It must return only one record

I tried something like this, but it isn't working:

```
declare @acSubject char(30)

set @acSubject = ''

select
case 
when acSubject = @acSubject then (select acCode  from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj where acSubject = @acSubject and acIdent = '201.2.013')
else (select top 1 acCode from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj where acIdent = '201.2.013')
end
from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj
where acIdent = '201.2.013'
and acSubject = @acSubject
```

Comment: Your first query logic does not make sense to me, because the code would not even run if it should return more than one record.

Comment: `select top 1` without an `order by` clause will return an arbitrary row. What column can you use for `order by`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When I leave it blank* means that it is `null` or `''`?
To cover both cases you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select
  case 
    when coalesce(rtrim(ltrim(@acSubject)), '') <> '' then (
      select acCode  from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj 
      where acSubject = @acSubject and acIdent = '201.2.013'
    )
    else (
      select top 1 acCode from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj 
      where acIdent = '201.2.013'
    )
  end acCode
```

This will work if the column `acSubject` is unique and the 1st case query returns only 1 row, otherwise you must use for it `top 1` too.
Another way to write the above logic would be:

```
select top 1 acCode 
from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj 
where 
  acIdent = '201.2.013'
  and 
  (coalesce(rtrim(ltrim(@acSubject)), '') = '' or acSubject = @acSubject)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `union`

```
declare @acSubject char(30)
set @acSubject = '' 

select acCode 
from (select acCode from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj where  acSubject = @acSubject  
      union  
      select case when @acSubject = '' then (select top 1 acCode from  tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj)  end 
)tbl
where acCode is not null
```